# NIO SelectionKey processing should it be single or multi threaded?

Tags: java, udp, nio

I m reading how Selector can multiplex multiple channels and do I/O operations whenever the channels are ready to be processed. Many online tutorials/resources uses something similar where they sequentially read each key, then process it.

```
            Set<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
            Iterator<SelectionKey> iter = selectedKeys.iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey key = iter.next();
                if (key.isReadable()) {
                    //processKey(key);
                }
                iter.remove();
            }
```

I m thinking that while Key 1 is being processed, all the keys (the sockets it represents) will still receive more incoming packets

```
Key 1 : [packet] [packet] [packet] [packet]
.
.
.
Key N : [packet] [packet] [packet] [packet]
```

So, if all channels receive 1 packets while key 1 has just processed 1 packets in the same time, wouldnt some channels have lost packets?

```
Key 1 :  [packet] [packet] [packet] [newPacket] 
.
.
.
Key N : [packet] [packet] [packet] [packet] [newPacket]
```

processing key 2

```
Key 1 : [packet] [packet] [packet] [newPacket] [newPacket] 
.
.
.
Key N : [packet] [packet] [packet] [packet] [newPacket] [newPacket]
```

processing key 3

```
Key 1 : [packet] [packet] [packet] [newPacket] [newPacket] {packet lost socket receive buffer full}
.
.
.
Key N : [packet] [packet] [packet] [packet] [newPacket] [newPacket] {packet lost socket receive buffer full}
```

Should each key be passed to a queue (then some other thread can poll for it) so that all keys can be processed in a multithreaded manner? What is an "optimal" number of channels I can register to a selector?

Comment: I found the answer by chance here at this [link](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-nio/0596002882/ch04.html). There is also a provided sample code in the link. _"A better approach is to use one selector for all selectable channels and delegate the servicing of ready channels to other threads. You have a single point to monitor channel readiness and a decoupled pool of worker threads to handle the incoming data. The thread pool size can be tuned (or tune itself, dynamically) according to deployment conditions. Management of selectable channels remains simple, and simple is good."_

Comment: I did as the link stated, and removed the READ from the key's interestOps before passing it to a separate thread. I think this is not the case for DatagramChannel compared to a socketChannel, because it is causing some errors where it eventually stops running entirely and blocks